# Is there a way to find multiple modes automatically in r?

Tags: r

I have a vector of values that I want to find statistical modes from. I recently learned about a function `multimode::locmodes` which finds the locations of modes as I wanted. However, I think the function assumes that I already know the *number* of modes existing in the data..?

For example, given this data `x`, I can plot a histogram to discover that there could be 3 modes. Then I can use `locmodes` with the number of modes `mod0 = 3` to get the locations. However, this approach requires that I should know value for `mod0` already? Is there a more programmatic approach to finding the value for `mod0`?

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- c(rnorm(250, 0.125, 0.03), rnorm(25, 0.85, 0.05), rnorm(200, 1.24, 0.02))
hist(x)
```

[image]

```r
mm <- multimode::locmodes(x, mod0 = 3)
mm
#> 
#> Estimated location
#> Modes: 0.1222717  0.853707   1.24139 
#> Antimodes: 0.4918366  1.060701 
#> 
#> Estimated value of the density
#> Modes:   4.4179  0.3331802  3.866845 
#> Antimodes: 8.32699e-13  0.001885466 
#> 
#> Critical bandwidth: 0.0383606
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately finding the number of modes is a very tough question - i.e., how do you decide what is a mode and what constitutes noise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over a vector of bandwidths

```
> bw <- seq.int(.02, .5, len=100)
> r <- sapply(bw, \(i) multimode::nmodes(x, i))
> plot(r, log='y', type='s', yaxt='n'); axis(2, 1:1e5)
```

and assess graphically

[image]

which suggests three modes, because the step from 3 to the next higher number is "very high". Maybe you could use 95% `quantile`, but even that doesn't provide much protection against arbitrariness.

```
> n_mod <- quantile(r, .95)
> mm <- multimode::locmodes(x, mod0=n_mod)
Warning message:
In multimode::locmodes(x, mod0 = n_mod) :
  If the density function has an unbounded support, artificial modes may have been created in the tails
> multimode::locmodes(x, mod0=n_mod, display=TRUE)

Estimated location
Modes: 0.1222717  0.853707   1.24139 
Antimodes: 0.4918366  1.060701 

Estimated value of the density
Modes:   4.4179  0.3331802  3.866845 
Antimodes: 8.326824e-13  0.001885466 

Critical bandwidth: 0.0383606

Warning message:
In multimode::locmodes(x, mod0 = n_mod, display = TRUE) :
  If the density function has an unbounded support, artificial modes may have been created in the tails
```

[image]

`multimode::sizer` also suggests three modes, check the references of `?multimode::sizer` to see how they are determined:

```
> summary(multimode::sizer(x, display=FALSE))

The estimated modes are located between the following values
(for the log10 bandwidths range indicated in parenthesis)

Mode 1:  0.10288 | 0.649395 (-1.672682 0.09191453)
Mode 2:  1.009708 | 1.253947 (-1.672682 -0.3487716)
Mode 3:  0.7920692 | 0.9226525 (-1.205673 -1.061009)
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(123)
x <- c(rnorm(250, 0.125, 0.03), rnorm(25, 0.85, 0.05), rnorm(200, 1.24, 0.02))
```

Comment: Difficult to see how this question could be answered any better. Bravo @jay.sf

Comment: @jay.sf Thank you so much for a great answer! I really like your approach with `multimode::nmodes`. I was reading up on the documentation of the function and it seems like it is estimating the number of "peaks" in a KDE? In your plot, with smaller `bw` (or the earlier indices), is the number of modes (or the `r` value) large because the KDE is too "noisy" and hence a lot of peaks?

Comment: @nightstand Note *BenBolker*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466599/is-there-a-way-to-find-multiple-modes-automatically-in-r/77466899?noredirect=1#comment136569410_77466599) above; if we do the KDE ourselves and adjust the bandwidth using smaller and smaller values, e.g. `density(x, kernel='gaussian', adjust=.05) |> plot(type='l')`, we can see that the number of modes is a decision and not an actual definable value. But yes, the sharp increase in the number of modes with smaller bandwidths could indicate something that we might want to attribute to noise.

Answer (score 2):

A quick-and-dirty method would be to find the peaks of a kernel density:

```r
with(density(x, bw = 0.05), x[which(diff(sign(diff(y))) == -2) + 1])
#> [1] 0.1221060 0.8584025 1.2400746
```

Note this gives near-identical results to `locmodes`.

Setting the `bw` parameter to a higher value acts as a way of smoothing out noise. It requires a bit of graphical exploration to find the correct value.